# Error creating default "bridge" network: cannot create network (docker0): conflicts with network (docker0): networks have same bridge name

Tags: docker

After stopping docker it refused to start again. It complaint that another bridge called docker0 already exists:

```
level=warning msg="devmapper: Base device already exists and has filesystem xfs on it. User specified filesystem  will be ignored."
level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"devicemapper\""
level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default \"bridge\" network: cannot create network fa74b0de61a17ffe68b9a8f7c1cd698692fb56f6151a7898d66a30350ca0085f (docker0): conflicts with network bb9e0aab24dd1f4e61f8e7a46d4801875ade36af79d7d868c9a6ddf55070d4d7 (docker0): networks have same bridge name"
docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Deleting the bridge with `ip link del docker0` and then starting docker leads to the same result with another id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem seems to be in `/var/docker/network/`. There are a lot of sockets stored that reference the bridge by its old id. To solve the Problem you can delete all sockets, delete the interface and then start docker **but all your container will refuse to work since their sockets are gone.** In my case I did not care about my stateless containers anyway so this fixed the problem:

```
ip link del docker0
rm -rf /var/docker/network/*
mkdir -p /var/docker/network/files
systemctl start docker
# delete all containers
docker ps -a | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs -n 1 echo docker rm  -f
# recreate all containers
```

Answer (score 24):

For me I downgraded my OS (Centos Atomic Host in this case) and came across this error message. The docker of the older Centos Atomic was 1.9.1. I did not have any running docker containers or images pulled before running the downgrade.

***I simply ran the below and docker was happy again:***

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/network
sudo systemctl start docker
```

[More info.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1399398)

Comment: this work for me, but all networks and containers is gone.

Comment: After hours of head banging.. this helped .. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It may sound obvious, but you may want to consider rebooting, especially if there was some major system update recently.
Worked for me, since I didn't reboot my VM after installing some kernel updates, which probably led to many network modules being left in an undefined state.

Comment: I made this same mistake (`pacman -Syu` had installed a kernel update).