# Error creating default \"bridge\" network: package not installed"

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi2

Suddently my docker daemon stop and never turned on again. I'm running docker on a Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+. It worked before until last week when my docker service suddenly stop working and I don't have a clue why.

My docker version is:

```
raspberrypi:~ $ docker version
```

`Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 22:23:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
 An error occurred trying to connect: Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.22/version: read unix /var/run/docker.sock: connection reset by peer`

Socket is ok:

```
● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; disabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Sat 2018-03-17 00:42:46 UTC; 6s ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)
```

Looking to my service status you can see the following log:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2018-03-17 00:05:52 UTC; 4min 55s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2891 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2891 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi docker[2891]: time="2018-03-17T00:05:52.743474604Z" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1)"
Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi docker[2891]: time="2018-03-17T00:05:52.758090386Z" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16)"
Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi docker[2891]: time="2018-03-17T00:05:52.772819345Z" level=debug msg="Cleaning up old shm/mqueue mounts: start."
Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi docker[2891]: time="2018-03-17T00:05:52.773269239Z" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default \"bridge\" network: package not installed"
Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 17 00:05:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524602/error-creating-default-bridge-network-cannot-create-network-docker0-conf) but for me it didn't work.

How can I make my docker service start again? It seems that a package is not installed but I tried to:

raspberrypi:~ $ modprobe bridge
modprobe: FATAL: Module bridge not found.