# Error response from daemon: failed to add IPv4 address 172.18.0.1/16 to bridge: file exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, chainlink

When running with `docker compose up` to run my docker, it complaints that "Failed to add IPv4 address 172.18.0.1/16 to bridge: file exists":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpBjX.png)

docker-compose.yml:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Tdt.png)

Restart the docker with `service docker restart` but lead to the same result.

Comment: does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524602/error-creating-default-bridge-network-cannot-create-network-docker0-confli

Comment: also check if your machine is configured to run ipV6 addresses?

Comment: Thank you all. I ran the docker in my WSL before and consider that there are some incompatible issues between the docker and WSL. I'll try it again on the Ubuntu virtual machine.